# How to use aura.log() and where does it print it output?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

Going trough the documentation for lightning I found the following line:

```
aura.log("current text: " + attributeValue);
```

I can't find any documentation about this method and I was wondering if there is any and also where can I find the log information. I though it would be on the browser console, but it's not there.

The link bellow will take you to the page where I found this method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm?search_text=aura.log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a read of [Log Messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_log_messages.htm?search_text=a.log) around `$A.log(string, [error])`.

> It outputs to the JavaScript console
>
> - `$A` is the shorthand in JavaScript code for the **Aura** object.
> - `$A.log()` doesn't output in **PROD** or **PRODDEBUG** modes.

You should either:

- "Enable Debug Mode", as per [Debugging JavaScript Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm?search_text=a.log).
- Write a custom client side logging function and subscribe it to the Aura logger. See [Logging in Production Modes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_log_messages.htm?search_text=a.log)

Also, see the related question [Salesforce1 Lightning Debug “log()” method not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/53831/102) where Peter covers some options for how to get it to output.