# Is $A.log (aura.log) long gone?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, logging

A colleague flagged the availability of `$A.log` (found in a blog) so we've spent a short while looking at it.

The links from e.g. [How to use aura.log() and where does it print it output?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/86322/how-to-use-aura-log-and-where-does-it-print-it-output) now point to simple `console.log` calls and there are posts here like [LockerService not allowing subscribing to $A.logger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129894/lockerservice-not-allowing-subscribing-to-a-logger). I don't see any official documentation on it (though [Aura Documentation](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs) is dead right now so I can't check there).

Can anyone explain why it went away?

Comment: The only reference i can see in lightning component bookshelf(in the spring 2018) one is its used in auraStorage:init as  an attribute for this storage method debugLoggingEnabled. There is no other reference  in bookshelf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We deprecated it.

We felt we should either implement something useful, or just not have it. So until the need arises for a proper implementation, its gone.